# Saving to Cloud Firestore on iOS hangs when offline

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Loading data from firestore while offline works as expected but a call to save never returns and there seems to be no timeout either.

This is a example save that works online but not offline:

```
func  save() {
    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return
    }
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("properties").addDocument(data: ["name": "test"]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any known workaround?

**UPDATE:** Firebase support have confirmed it's a bug and that it "is now being worked on by our engineers". They are unable to give a timescale for when it will be fixed.

Comment: Any progress on this? We have the same issue :/

Comment: Over half a year since you posted this and I just ran into the same situation. Ugh, doesn't seem promising for a quick fix. Do you have a trouble ticket link/ID so I can follow it? Thanks.

Comment: arrrgh,,,  just ran into this now too. Quick fix? Google is strapped for resources obviously

Comment: we are also facing this....

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour - you should assume that the write will happen when the device comes back online. In my use cases, I've just continued with the normal flow and used my local data as my source of truth.

It's mentioned here: https://youtu.be/XrltP8bOHT0?t=680

Comment: Nice share, video is helpful.